# unhashable type list issue while scraping a web page

Tags: python, json, regex, web-scraping, scrapy

This question is kind of a follow up to a previous question I asked.

[Scraping data from a http & javaScript site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54057433/scraping-data-from-a-http-javascript-site?noredirect=1#comment94949200_54057433)

New errors have appeared so, I'm stuck on those right now.

The code is the same as the previous question, something along the lines of

```
cothesAmz_item = ClothesItem()
    #info de producto
    script = response.xpath('//script/text()').extract()
    data = re.findall(script, '(\{.+?\}_')

    d = json.loads(data[0])

    cothesAmz_item['nombreProducto'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//span[contains(@id, "productTitle")]/text())').extract()

    yield cothesAmz_item
```

I have tried printing the script and it works, it's a giant amount of text but, it prints something.

The problem I'm having now is the regular expression one. When the code reaches

```
data = re.findall(script, '(\{.+?\}_')
```

Which should take within 'data' everything that's between brackets, I get the unhashable type 'list' error.

With this, I want to, after going through

```
d = json.loads(data[0])
```

Get a sort of dictionary in which I can be able to extract data from the page

Is this error coming from a bad use of re.findall or is it somewhere else in the code? (maybe there is an easier way to achieve this)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Typically, the first and second arguments of `findall` must both be strings. As a first step, I suggest that you try to determine the type of `script`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.findall` function takes both `arguments` as `string` but

```
script = response.xpath('//script/text()').extract()
```

returns a list.

if script list is more than one element use:

```
script = ' '.joins(script)    #convert list to string
```

if its a single element in the list then:

```
data = re.finall(script[0], 'your regex').
```

Comment: thanks for the help! I ran into another issue while running the code. I found in which 'slot' the string i wanted was but, when running data = re.findall(script[i], '(\{.+?\}_'). Nothing seems go into data. What I'm trying to get into 'data' is everything that's inside { }

Comment: Let me have a look at your prev. question to understand what you need actually.

Comment: please read your orev. question. and tell me if this is what you want, then, convert them to json and use them as separate variables. :)